# 本番環境でリクエストへのレスポンスが返ってこない

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, cors

本番環境へnode.jsとreact.jsで構成されたアプリを載せたところ、フロントからリクエストは送れるものの、レスポンスがない状況です。

corsのアクセスが原因だと思いますが、エンドポイントは問題なく設定できていると思います。フロントエンドはvercelで、バックエンドはherokuにデプロイをしています。どのようにすればレスポンスを得られるでしょうか？またプラットフォームを他のものに切り替えるなどすれば、レスポンスが返却されるなどありますでしょうか？

### ソース

```
app.use(function(res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});
    
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'https://reactjs-realtime-chat.vercel.app', //アクセス許可するオリジン
  credentials: true, //レスポンスヘッダーにAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials追加
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 //レスポンスstatusを200に設定
}))
```

[image: Login.jsx]

[image: apiCalls.js]

ログイン機能さえ、うまくいけば、本番環境での利用はできそうです。
user情報をどのようにすれば、postして認証できるのかに躓いてます。

バグはログインで情報をpostした際に発生をしています。ユーザー情報のリクエストはできているので、レスポンスを得られるようにしたいです。

### エラー内容

[image: DevToolでのコンソール出力内容]

axioswrapperをconsole.logでわかるように記載しています。
このdataを取れるようにしたいです。dataはそもそも定義しなくてもいい認識なんですが、、、

Comment: エラーメッセージを質問欄を編集して追記して下さい。プリフライトリクエストが必要なのにその設定がされてないと言うことはありませんか？